# Chat system db design - one to one and group - Laravel, redis, socket.io, node

Tags: php, laravel, redis, socket.io, chat

I want to know how can build db structure for
chat system - one to one and group.
I'm using MySQL.

I'm using
Laravel, redis, socket.io

I just create simple chat to understand stack

How I'm working

Client 1 msg -> Laravel save in db and push in redis ->
Node redis client listen -> socket.io send to -> Client 2

How it work for group chat not live chat?

Comment: also, post what you tried

Comment: This is a much too generic question.  You will need to do some of the work yourself, and narrow down your question to specifics once you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build something like that with minimal columns

`chat` **(one to one)**

```
id | message | message_type | sender | reciever | reply_to (optional) | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at (optional)
```

`chat_messages` **(group)**

```
id | group_id | message | message_type | sender | reply_to (optional) | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at (optional)
```

You have to define `groups` (group_id - relation) if you want to implement

You can prefer the above example only basic functionality is there. you can update based on your logic